# Managing secret in AWS Secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, serverless

I am deploying network VPC in AWS using Terraform. We have a standard-defined CIDR range for VPC within the R&D organization.

Here is my Terraform block to create VPC.

```
    resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr   # "10.32.0.0/24"
  instance_tenancy = "default"
  tags = {
    "Name" = "file-transfer-vpc-${var.environment}"
  }
}
```

I am wondering if I can invoke third-party API in Terraform to get

```
vpc_cidr
```

and pass it to the VPC module from the main.tf file. Terraform documentation doesn't have any example of third-party API.

Currently, I have defined CIDR manually in .tfvar file and used the below commands to pass when Terraform is running.

```
terraform plan -var-file="dev.auto.tfvars"
terraform apply -var-file="dev.auto.tfvars"
```

Please help if anyone has implemented a similar use case before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach I like to use in these use-cases is `data` resources. You can simply provide the name of the VPC, and using a `data` resource fetch all the data of this resource from AWS at runtime.

This is an example from TF docs

```
variable "vpc_id" {}

data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.selected.id
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(data.aws_vpc.selected.cidr_block, 4, 1)
}
```

This way you only need to keep the logic names as vars, and not the internal data (such as CIDRs, subnet addressing, etc.)

You can use `data` blocks to fetch information about many types of resources. Check out [Terraform Data Sources docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources).

I also post a blogpost on why I prefer to use `data` sources over remote state [here.](https://devopsian.net/posts/terraform-data-sources-over-remote-state/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through terraform documentation and I think there is pretty good approach to handle sensitive data in terraform. It is good fit for my case as it contains mostly IPs, CIDRs, external system endpoints. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/sensitive-variables